# Social Networking site creation using only PHP, HTML, CSS, Javascript, ajax , jquery and xml

Tags: xml

It's a university final project for our Web Development class and we are required to create a social networking site without using sql and only using xml as database.

Comment: What is your question? Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck.

Comment: I'm stuck with things that have something to do with AJAX and jQuery.  By the way, it is a requirement per page that shows up and no alert boxes are allowed.